# Touchpad - Removing Middle Button Area by enabling Middle Button Emulation (Ubuntu 17.10 - Gnome 3.26 - Wayland)

Tags: gnome, touchpad, 17.10, wayland

(My touchpad is just one big square and the buttons are based on the area that you click)

**Goal:** I want my touchpad to ONLY have a left and right click and I want to disable the default middle button functionality.

**How to accomplish:** Although it may seem counterintuitive at first, I want to do this by enabling middle button emulation.  This will effectively remove the middle button area from the touchpad and only cause a middle button press event when both the right and left buttons are pressed simultaneously.

**Question: How do I enable middle button emulation on a fresh default install of Ubuntu 17.10 (Gnome 3.26.2 & Wayland) ?**

**Other info / things I've tried:**
My touchpad works well by default, but I keep on hitting the middle button by accident and that causes bad things to happen.  I've tried switching up the Click-method with the gnome-tweak-tool, but I like those options even less.  I've tried using xinput set-button-map and xinput set-int-prop but it seems to me that either it only works within certain applications (not system-wide) or that xinput does not work with Wayland.  I've tried looking into libinput, but I'm unsure how use it.

I've read some bug threads on this issue and libinput people say that if you enable middle button emulation, then that will effectively remove the middle button from area and only cause a middle button press event when both the right and left buttons are pressed simultaneously.  This is the fix that I want to implement, but I can't figure out how to do it.

https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/middle_button_emulation.html
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput